# How can I boot into TWRP from LineageOS Recovery?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, boot-loop, lineageos

My phone is in bootloop. It keeps booting to TWRP Recovery. I want to trouble shoot this. How can I boot into TWRP to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To boot into TWRP from LineageOS Recovery, from LineageOS Recovery

- Click Advanced
- Click Reboot to Bootloader

Jump to the console on your machine, and run

```
fastboot boot twrp-*.img
```

That'll get you into TWRP from LineageOS Recovery.